# Text link to <a href='...'> // JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, ios, hyperlink

I have some text like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. site.com
>   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
>   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
>   **itunes.apples.ru.com/app/forge-of-empires/id711455226** ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
>   incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. site.com Ut enim ad minim
>   veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
>   ea commodo consequat

But all links are inactive. So I want them to be clickable. And in HTML it should look like this:
`<a href='http://itunes.apples.ru.com/app/forge-of-empires/id711455226'>Download on iTunes</a>` *//everything after /app/ varies depending on the link.*

Also, I **can't** use any symbols like quotes `"`. Only single quotes `'`.

Comment: go through the regex....

Answer (score 2):

I hope this could help you, used single quotes for anchor link

HTML Markup

```
 <h2>Plain Content</h2> <div id="before">Find me at
 http://gmkhussain.github.io/ and also at
 https://linkedin.com/in/gmkhussain</div>

 <h2>URLify</h2> <div id="after"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function urlifyFn(text) {
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        return "<a href='" + url + "'>" + url + "</a>";
    })
    // or alternatively
    // return text.replace(urlRegex, '<a href="$1">$1</a>')
}

var text = document.getElementById("before").innerHTML;
var html = urlifyFn(text);

document.getElementById("after").innerHTML = html;
```

See link : https://codepen.io/gmkhussain/pen/jgMZJO